# How can we compress DNA string efficiently

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression, dna-sequence, lossless-compression

DNA strings can be of any length comprising any combination of the 5 alphabets (A, T, G, C, N).
What could be the efficient way of compressing DNA string of alphabet comprising 5 alphabets (A, T, G, C, N). Instead of considering 3 bits per alphabet, can we compress and retrieve efficiently using less number of bits? Can anybody suggest a pseudo code for efficient compression and retrieval?

Comment: just a thought... you can use 7 bits to encode sequences of 3 letters in order to waste less bits

Comment: Potential candidate for Run length encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Comment: Why not use off the shelf compression solutions?

Comment: @Sorin Because, depending on what you mean by “off the shelf”, they work fairly badly on DNA. Algorithms that know specifics about DNA can do much better.

Comment: @user463035818 idea is very good, that will give you 2.3333 bits in average per symbol.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel I just tried for what sequence length `log2( 5^n)` is closest to the next bigger integer and `n=3` seems to be a good choice

Comment: Does this need to be specific and efficient? Tools like 7zip and gzip will compress it to a size that will be hard to improve, but they will take much more time than a specialized solution

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree with your point. It's my impression that the setup right now has no compression (other than custom alphabet encoding). So even something suboptimal should compress better than no compression.

Comment: @Sorin Not necessarily: by definition, a compression algorithm cannot compress all data, and random data may even result in bigger files than the original. This isn’t theoretical, I’ve seen DNA sequence files that were bigger after gzip compression than uncompressed, repeatedly.

Comment: @user463035818: In case you chose 3 "by accident", it happens to make a lot of sense biologically. ATGC represent nucleotides. 3 nucleotides form a codon, and each codon codifies a specific amino acid. N is a wildcard.

Comment: @MSalters maybe you missed my second comment, I choose 3 because it appeared most efficient to me (at least for anything up to length 5) and maybe nature just followed the same reasoning when forming the codons :P

Comment: @Dani See my comments further up. These tools aren’t necessarily terribly good at DNA, which often has pretty high (first-order) entropy.

Comment: @user463035818 Nature kinda does, but slightly differently: there’s no “N” in nature, and codons need to encode 20 (± a bit) different amino acids. Now what’s the minimal number of symbols from an alphabet of size 4 needed to encode 20 words?

Comment: It hardly depends on what you are doing with that compressed strings. If you just pack/unpack to store them is one thing, if you work with them in memory then completely another.

Comment: @KonradRudolph awesome, in the end it all boils down to number theory, we just need a couple of centuries more to understand ;)

Comment: `retrieve efficiently` - "random access" or "sequential from the start" (see `(b)` from [Roee Gavirel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51859381/3789665))? For random access, 5³ is just below 2⁷: encode the bases (what does `N` stand for?) three at a time (see [user463035818's commnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859259/how-can-we-compress-dna-string-efficiently#comment90671590_51859259)) using 7 bits.

Answer (score 7):

you can if you willing to (a) have different bits size for each char and (b) you are always reading from the start and never from the middle. then, you can have a code something like:

- A - 00
- T - 01
- G - 10
- C - 110
- N - 111

Reading from left to right you can only split a stream of bits to chars in one way. You read 2 bits at a time and if they are "11" you need to read one more bit to know what char it is.

[This is based on Huffman Coding Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-3-huffman-coding/)

Note:
I don't know much about DNA, but if the probability of the chars is not equal (meaning 20% each). you should assign the shortest codes to those with the higher probability.

Comment: I like this. Theoretically, log₂(5) ≈ 2.32 bits are needed per symbol. This uses an average of 12 / 5 = 2.4 bits per symbol. Reminds me of UTF encoding.

Comment: Also because of Huffman Coding Algorithm you can set smallest sequence(like 11 10 or 01) to most used one. So total bit is need even smaller.

Comment: When you write digits, do you mean bits?

Comment: @wally - true, fixed (;

Comment: The probability of the symbols is indeed *anything but* equal. For starters, most sequences will probably have fewer Ns than any other letter but this depends on the process that generated the sequence. Next, although the individual frequencies of A, C, G and T are somewhat even, there’s furthermore a rough equilibrium between the sum of A + T and C + G. Consequently I would make the words such that the lengths of A=C and G=T (or A=G and C=T), to balance things as much as possible. Unfortunately this doesn’t work if we assign N the longest word.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - There is no actual need `to balance things as much as possible`. Even if p(A)=p(C) they can have different length code. Giving N, the symbol with the lowest probability, the longest word will create the shortest output.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel Right, *if* they have the same frequency. My point is that we generally don’t know this, but conversely we know that p(C) + p(G) ≈ p(A) + p(T).

Comment: You could also just count each symbol and then prefix the final stream with the encoding for each of them. The prefix could have only 9-10 bits, and it would save a lot more of them.

Answer (score 3):

You have 5 unique values, so you need a base-5 encoding (e.g. A=0, T=1, G=2, C=3, N=4).

In 32 bits you can fit log<sub>5</sub>(2<sup>32</sup>) = **13** base-5 values.

In 64 bits you can fit log<sub>5</sub>(2<sup>64</sup>) = **27** base-5 values.

The encoding process would be:

```
uint8_t *input = /* base-5 encoded DNA letters */;
uint64_t packed = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 27; ++i) {
    packed = packed * 5 + *input++;
}
```

And decoding:

```
uint8_t *output = /* allocate buffer */;
uint64_t packed = /* next encoded chunk */;
for (int i = 0; i < 27; ++i) {
    *output++ = packed % 5;
    packed /= 5;
}
```

Comment: Your code works as long as the result fits into 64 bits. That’s rarely the case ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph just split the input up into chunks of 27 values and repeat, outputting 64 bits after each iteration.

Comment: That wastes bits at the boundary.

Comment: It wastes <1/2 bit per 64 bits. We've found that it beats the huffman coding in many cases, especially if the probability of input characters isn't well-balanced. With a good bigint library (e.g. GMP) one can extend the chunk size to 512 bits or more to further reduce the waste.

Comment: I think it wastes a bit more, about 64 - log₂(5) * 27 ≈ 1.3 bits per 64 bits. Or you might say it wastes 64 / log₂(5) - 27 ≈ .56 symbols per 64 bits. Still pretty good though.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of methods to compress, but the main question is what data you want to compress?
 1. Raw unaligned sequenced data from the sequencing machine (fastq)
 2. Aligned data (sam/bam/cram)
 3. Reference genomes

1. You should reorder your reads putting reads from the close genome positions close to each other. For instance, this would allow usual gzip compress 3 times better. There are many ways to do this. You can for instance align fastq to bam and than export back to fastq. Use Suffix Tree/Array to find similar reads, the way most aligners work (needs a lot of memory). Use minimizers - very fast, low memory solution, but not good for long reads with many errors. Good results are from debruijn graph construction, which is used for the purpose (aka de-novo alignment).
   Statistical coding like huffman / arithmetic would compress to 1/3 (one can pass huffman stream to binary arithmetic coder to gain another 20%).
2. The best results are from reference-based compressions here - just store differences between a reference and the aligned read.
3. Little can be done here. Using statistical coding you can get 2-3 bits per nucleotide.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a combination of Roee Gavirel's idea and the following for an even tighter result. Since Roee's idea still stipulates that two out of our five characters be mapped to a 3-bit word, sections of the sequence where at least one of the five characters does not appear but one of the 3-bit words does could be mapped to 2-bit words, reducing our final result.

The condition to switch mapping is if there exists a section where at least one of the five characters does not appear and one of the 3-bit words appears just one time more than two times our section-prefix length in bits. If we order our possible characters (for example, alphabetically), given three bits indicating a specific missing character (if there's more than one missing, we choose the first in order) or none missing, we can immediately assign a consistent 2-bit mapping for the other four characters.

Two ideas for our prefixes:

(1)

- 3 bits: the missing character (if none, we use Roee's encoding for the section);
- x bits: a constant number of bits representing section length. For maximal length sections of 65000, we could assign x = 16.

To justify the prefix use, we'd need a section where one of the five characters does not appear and one of the 3-bit words appears 39 times or more.

(2)

- 3 bits: the missing character (if none, we use Roee's encoding for the section);
- x bits: the number of bits in the next section of the prefix - depends on how many characters the longest section could be. x = 6 would imply the maximal section length could be 2^(2^6)! Unlikely. For maximal length sections of 65000, we could assign x = 4;
- the number of bits indicated in the previous part of the prefix, indicating the current section length.

In the example just above, our prefix length could vary between say 11 and 23 bits, which means to justify its use, we'd need a section where one of the five characters does not appear and one of the 3-bit words appears between 23 to 47 times or more.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I would start with some version of Lempel-Ziv compression (a class of compression algorithms that includes the general-purpose `gzip` compression format).  I note that some of the comments say that general-purpose compression algorithms don't work well on raw genome data, but their effectiveness depends on how the data is presented to them.

Note that most general-purpose compression programs (like `gzip`) examine their input on a per-byte basis.  This means that "pre-compressing" the genome data at 3 bits/base is *counterproductive*; instead, you should format the uncompressed genome data at one byte per base before running it through a general-purpose compressor.  Ascii "AGTCN" coding should be fine, as long as you don't add noise by including spaces, newlines, or variations in capitalization.

Lempel-Ziv compression methods work by recognizing repetitive substrings in their input, then encoding them by reference to the preceding data; I'd expect this class of methods should do a reasonably good job on appropriately presented genome data.  A more genome-specific compression method may improve on this, but unless there's some strong, non-local constraint on genome encoding that I'm unaware of, I would not expect a major improvement.

Comment: If the data does not have significant repetitive patterns, will this type of compression reduce the footprint per character as well?

Comment: It likely depends on the details of the compression method, but I'd expect it might do roughly as well as a first-order Huffman encoder if the file is reasonably long.

Comment: Note that, if the data really does not have any significant repetitive patterns, then by definition all you've got to compress on is first-order statistics (i.e., individual symbol frequency).  In that case, you wouldn't be able to do much better than a first-order Huffman encoder anyway...